# cocos2dX setBlendFunc

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, sprite

My image looks like there is too much black. I use the function `setBlendFunc`.

But When the sprite does not run Animate, it will work. If run, it does not work. How can this be fixed?

```
CCSprite *effectSprite=CCSprite::create("init_black.png");
effectSprite->setBlendFunc((ccBlendFunc) {GL_ONE, GL_ONE});
SoliderSprite *enemySolider=(SoliderSprite *)(enemy->objectAtIndex(0));
CCArray *position=enemySolider->soliderPosition;
position->retain();
cout<<((CCString *)position->objectAtIndex(0))->intValue()<<endl;
effectSprite->setPosition(ccp(((CCString *)position->objectAtIndex(0))->intValue(),((CCString *)position->objectAtIndex(1))->intValue()));
this->addChild(effectSprite);
string effectString="effect";
if(this->direction)
{
    msg.property[1].append("L");
}
else 
{
    msg.property[1].append("R");
}

CCAnimate *effectAction=animate->createWithKind(msg.property[1],effectString.c_str(),2);
effectSprite->runAction(effectAction);

position->release();
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that is a bug and new version does not have that problem.
Try this code with version 2.1.5 of cocos2d-x:

```
CCSprite someSprite = CCSprite.spriteWithFile("someImage");
ccBlendFunc someBlend = new ccBlendFunc();
someBlend.src = OGLES.GL_ONE;
someBlend.dst = OGLES.GL_ONE;
someSprite.BlendFunc = someBlend;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the render mode is not what you want to show the final effect.
How about using:

```
SRC = GL_SRC_ALPHA,
SRC = GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA
```